# Execute POST request until network connection available with Volley on Android

Tags: android, http, networking, connection, android-volley

I've been wondering if there is any way with Volley to queue and then execute a request until the mobile data connection is available.

I have to create an Android app that have to work in areas with no mobile service, so I have to queue and postpone any POST request that my app perform using Volley, until the internet mobile service is available.

The app have a registration form that have to be filled, and when I press send, if there is mobile service the form is sent, but if not, the form information have to be store and the POST request have to be queue in order to be performed later when the phone count with service connection.

Is there any way to do this with Volley? Or with any other Android HTTP Connection library.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saved my information to a database on the device with a "transmitted" flag. This way, even if the user completely closes the app, the information is always saved.

I then created a service (https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) that checks every 15 minutes for records that have not been transmitted. If they are found, it tries to transmit again.

The transmit is also executed as soon as a user enters and saves the information. Successful transmissions update the "transmitted" flag on the record.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed and works like I charm.

Comment: Be sure you also include a process that goes through and deletes old transmissions when the appropriate amount of time has passed. Don't want the records building up of long periods.

Comment: I think using a connectivity receiver that starts sending untransmitted requests as soon as connection is available is a better idea than checking every 15 minutes. Anyway, can you provide the source code?

Comment: I would be interested in the source as well. Thank you in advance.